# Find customers who ordered in the last week every day?

Tags: sql, oracle

Recently i was asked a question in the interview. Which is there is a customer table and an order table. How to get the customers who ordered in the last week everyday and how to find the customers who order in last three consecutive days?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Can you write a query when you you don't know the definitions of the tables?  No?  Well, neither can anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

To get customers who ordered every day for the past N days I would try something like:

```
select customer_id
  from orders
  where trunc(order_date) > trunc(sysdate) - :N
  group by customer_id
  having count(distinct trunc(order_date)) = :N
```

The idea is that the `WHERE` clause limits your data to orders made within the last N days, then we `GROUP BY` to form a group for each customer, and then in the `HAVING` clause we check each customer to see if `COUNT(DISTINCT TRUNC(ORDER_DATE))` equals N.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the order table to a wide table with columns corresponding to each day of interest. Not sure if there are better ways.

Answer (score 0):

A brute force method uses `exists`.  For instance, for the last three days:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where exists (select 1
              from orders o
              where o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                    trunc(o.order_date) = trunc(sysdate)
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from orders o
              where o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                    trunc(o.order_date) = trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day
             ) and
      exists (select 1
              from orders o
              where o.customer_id = c.customer_id and
                    trunc(o.order_date) = trunc(sysdate) - interval '2' day
             ) ;
```

This is one method.  There are others, that I'll let you think about.